# Manipulating request entity using HttpRequestInterceptor in Apache HttpClient

Tags: apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

HttpRequest does not have getters for the Request entity to allow me to manipulate it in an interceptor. Checking the type using instanceof is not working either. Would anybody have any ideas about how I can accomplish this?

```
public class FastinfosetRequestInterceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor 
{

@Override
public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context)
        throws HttpException, IOException 
{
    if(request instanceof HttpPost)
    {
        HttpEntity rqEntity = ((HttpPost)request).getEntity();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rqEntity.writeTo(baos);
        byte[] encodedRq;
        try 
        {
            encodedRq = FastInfosetUtils.encodeToFastInfoSet(baos.toByteArray());
        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException
                | TransformerException e) 
        {
            throw new IOException("Error while encoding request to FastInfoSet", e);
        }
        ((HttpPost) request).setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(encodedRq));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix the problem

```
if(request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)
{
    HttpEntity rqEntity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request).getEntity();
```